# Check if date is in next 10 days python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I have a problem with my code. I have a list with dates and I want that every date which is in the next 10 days in this list, is appended into another list. But my code isn't working like I expected that.

Code:

```py
    """
    Logic to sort into dates in the next 10 days
    -> Creates timedelta with 10 days, future date
    -> Checksif there is an date in the next days, which is a public holiday
    """
    list_upcoming_raw = []
    ten_days = timedelta(days=10)
    future_date = datetime.datetime.now() + ten_days
    today = datetime.datetime.now()

    for i in data_list:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%y%m%d')
        if date <= future_date and date >= today:
            list_upcoming_raw.append(date.date())
    list_upcoming_raw.sort()

    start_date = None
        end_date = None
        list_upcoming = []
        for date in list_upcoming_raw:
            if end_date is None or date == end_date + timedelta(days=1):
                end_date = date
            else:
                 if start_date is not None:
                    list_upcoming.append(f"{start_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}")
                start_date = date
                end_date = date

        if start_date is not None:
            list_upcoming.append(f"{start_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}-{end_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}")
```

Example of stuff inside the list:

```
231002
231003
231004
231005
231006
231009
231010
231011
231012
231013
231030
231031
240223
240328
240329
240401
240402
240403
240404
240405
240501
240508
240509
240510
240520
240521
240620
240621
240624
240625
240626
240312
240313
240314
240315
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you expecting and what results do you get?

Comment: _But my code isn't working like I expected_ This does not tell us anything about the actual problem.  Please show us the **actual results** of the code, and show us **exactly** what you expected instead.

Comment: I'm getting this list:
```py
['07.08.2023', '14.08.2023', '02.10.2023', '09.10.2023', '30.10.2023', '22.11.2023', '11.12.2023', '25.12.2023', '01.01.2024', '12.02.2024', '19.02.2024-23.02.2024']
```

But I expect, that I only get dates, which are in the next 10 days

Comment: You can't possibly be getting that output, because those are strings, but the code actually produces `date.date()` values.

Comment: I'm getting this list, because I have another logic above which do that. If it's needed for some reason, I edited the post

Comment: `if date <= future_date` Dates in the past also satisfy this condition.  If you want to exclude past dates, you also need to check `date >= today`.

Comment: Like that?

```py
list_upcoming_raw = []
    ten_days = timedelta(days=10)
    future_date = datetime.datetime.now() + ten_days
    today = datetime.datetime.now()

    for i in data_list:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%y%m%d')
        if date <= future_date and date >= today:
            list_upcoming_raw.append(date.date())
    list_upcoming_raw.sort()
```

Comment: None of the dates in the list above are in the next ten days.  The only ones before ten days from now are in the past.

Comment: Oh sorry, shit formatting. I changed it in my question... But this change helped not, now I'm getting every time a list with 0 items

Comment: Yes, but I also have a test list where are dates which are in the next 10 days to test f its working:

```py
data_list = ['240312', '240319', '240521', '230305', '240320', '240321', '240421']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the corrected code:

```
import datetime

# Example list of dates in string format
data_list = [
    '240223', '240328', '240329', '240401', '240402', '240403',
    '240404', '240405', '240501', '240508', '240509', '240510',
    '240520', '240521', '240620', '240621', '240624', '240625', '240626'
]

# Initial setup
list_upcoming_raw = []
ten_days = datetime.timedelta(days=10)
future_date = datetime.datetime.now() + ten_days

# Process each date in the data list
for i in data_list:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%y%m%d')
    
    # Check if the date is within the next 10 days
    if date <= future_date:
        list_upcoming_raw.append(date.date())

list_upcoming_raw.sort()

for d in list_upcoming_raw:
    print(d)
```

Comment: This solution is also not working... Greets